# converting native SAS datetime to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, sas

Been trying to change a native SAS datetime value to an oracle one-
ie. 1788130680 converts to 29AUG2016:22:58:00
I had attempted to do this:

```
 to_date('01/01/1960','DD/MM/YYYY')+ 1788130680
```

but no dice. Suggestions appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a number of seconds since January 1st, 1960. You can turn it to a date as follows:

```
date '1960-01-01' + 1788130680 / 60 / 60 / 24
```

The idea is to conver the number to days (by dividing it by the number of seconds there is in a day), and then add it to the starting date.

It might be easier to understand by using an `interval`:

```
date '1960-01-01' + 1788130680 * interval '1' second
```

Comment: Thanks. Helps immensely!